# How to use timestamp option in ping

Tags: bash, ping

I noticed that there is a timestamp option -T in the ping help. But I don't know how to use it.

I tried:

```
ping www.google.com -T
```

This is what I get:

```
Invalid timestamp type
```

What is the timestamp type and how do I use it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `-T` option is used to ask hops to insert the timestamp in the IP packets upon receiving the ping. It works by using the `TS` option of IP packets, specified by [RFC791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791).

`ping -T` requires an argument: one of **`tsonly`**, **`tsandaddr`** or **`tsprespec`**. You can read the manpage [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man8/ping.8.html) or by running `man ping` for more information on the usage.

Here's an example of usage:

```
$ ping -T tsandaddr 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(124) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=3.22 ms
TS:     192.168.1.3 63668917 absolute
    192.168.1.1 534841740 absolute not-standard
    192.168.1.1 1 not-standard
    192.168.1.3 3

64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=6.59 ms
TS:     192.168.1.3 63669919 absolute
    192.168.1.1 534842745 absolute not-standard
    192.168.1.1 0 not-standard
    192.168.1.3 6

64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=3.20 ms
TS:     192.168.1.3 63670920 absolute
    192.168.1.1 534843743 absolute not-standard
    192.168.1.1 1 not-standard
    192.168.1.3 3

^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 3.207/4.343/6.599/1.595 ms
```

Note that I've tried on my LAN. Some hops on the internet may reject IP packets with the timestamp option. (In fact, I cannot ping any internet host with `-T`, probably my ISP is rejecting my packets.)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you want to log uptime of a link or host, you probably want a one-line response with a timestamp, eg:

```
ping -i 10 google.com | while read pong; do echo "$(date): $pong"; done
```

This will send a ping every ten seconds with `-i 10` then pipe this to a file, eg add `>  /tmp/ping_google.log`. Output like:

```
Sat Jan 22 07:34:08 AEDT 2022: PING google.com (172.217.6.78) 56(84) bytes of data.
Sat Jan 22 07:34:08 AEDT 2022: 64 bytes from sfo07s17-in-f78.1e100.net (172.217.6.78): icmp_seq=1 ttl=118 time=2.27 ms
Sat Jan 22 07:34:18 AEDT 2022: 64 bytes from sfo07s17-in-f78.1e100.net (172.217.6.78): icmp_seq=2 ttl=118 time=1.32 ms
Sat Jan 22 07:34:28 AEDT 2022: 64 bytes from sfo07s17-in-f78.1e100.net (172.217.6.78): icmp_seq=3 ttl=118 time=1.34 ms
...
```

Hope this helps someone.